# Convert 8 bit image to 32 bit in OpenCV 2

Tags: image, opencv

How can I convert an 8 bit mat to a 32 bit mat to use in the kmeans function. I tried to use ConvertScale, but the compiler said it was an unknown function. I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 and want to avoid using the API calls from older versions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `convertTo`

```
cv::Mat mat = do your thing using CV_8S (or CV_8U)
cv::Mat dst = do your other thing
mat.convertTo(dst, CV_32S);
```

Comment: This is right for the C++ API. If you are working with the Python API, you can use NumPy. Assuming A is CV_8UC1: B = array(A, dtype=float32)

Comment: @TH nearly has it.. In order to convert an image to 32 bit in numpy, you also need to divide the value of each value by 256 as   img_32 = np.array(img / 256.0, dtype=np.float32). This is because 8bit image values are between 0..255 and 32 bit images are between 0...1