# NumPy convert 8-bit to 16/32-bit image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I am using OpenCV 2 to do some images manipulations in YCbCr color space. For the moment I can detect some noise due to the conversion RGB -> YCbCr and then YCbCr -> RGB, but as said in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html):

> If you use cvtColor with 8-bit images, the conversion will have some information lost. For many applications, this will not be noticeable but it is recommended to use 32-bit images in applications that need the full range of colors or that convert an image before an operation and then convert back.

So I would like to convert my image in 16 or 32 bits, but I didn't found how to do it with NumPy. Some ideas?

```
img = cv2.imread(imgNameIn)
# Here I want to convert img in 32 bits
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB, img)
# Some image processing ...
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR, img)
cv2.imwrite(imgNameOut, img, [cv2.cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
```

Comment: For a hint see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8976502/2379410

Comment: If it solves your problem, please write it as an answer and accept it so that it will be marked as "SOLVED".

Comment: Sorry I don't see any button to accept the answer and mark the problem as solved, how should I do?

Comment: @user3263033 you need to post an answer to your question, then click the tick mark next to your answer in order to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @moarningsun, problem resolved:

```
i = cv2.imread(imgNameIn, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR) # Need to be sure to have a 8-bit input
img = np.array(i, dtype=np.uint16) # This line only change the type, not values
img *= 256 # Now we get the good values in 16 bit format
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not accurate. A 16-bit image has 65536 intensity levels (`2^16`) hence, values ranging from `0` to `65535`.

If one wants to obtain a 16-bit image from an image represented as an array of `float` ranging from 0 to 1, one has to multiply every coefficient of this array by `65535`.

Also, it is good practice to cast the type of your end result as the very last step of the operations you perform. 
This is mainly for two reasons:
 - If you perform divisions or multiplications by `float`, the result will return a `float` and you will need to change the type again.
 - In general (in the mathematical sense of the term), a transformation from float to integer can introduce errors. Casting the type at the very end of the operations prevents error propagation.

Comment: "result f a multiplication ... returns in general a float` -- Could you, please, provide some demonstrations of this happening?

Comment: @DanMašek I meant "in general" in the mathematical sense of the term - At least once.
I re-wrote what I had in mind in a clearer way. Thank you for pointing out that my answer was confusing.

Comment: you can also use `cv2.normalize(img, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=65535, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)` to get the right 16bit values