# How i can convert a 16 bit depth image (png format) into a 32 bit one?

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, depth

I have a depth image 16 uint of an human hand, after thresholding. I want to recover some geometric features as contour, convex hull, etc., but all these functions work with 8 or 32 bit images so I need to convert. I'm working in python!

I've tried with some open cv function as

```
img32 = np.array(thresh, dtype=np.float32) # This line only change the type, not values
img32 *= 65536 # Now we get the good values in 32 bit format
print img.dtype
```

but I've always a 16 uint image.

Comment: Related, probably answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24444334

Comment: What is the image format ? It is compressed or raw ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hi! I've just tried in the same way more  or less, i think :) but nothing...@Spirine Hi, yes it's compressed, it's an image from kinect saved as png, that i'm using to make some test for my master degree thesis. It's a 16uint depth image that i've binarized with an otsu's thresholding and now i have a black and white image in which i want to find some geometrical features in opencv but many functions that i need require 8 or 32 bit images

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe PNG supports floating point data, so I am not sure what format you expect the output to be in?

If raw 32-bit float RGB is ok, you could use ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and readily avilable for OS X and Windows. The command would be

```
convert input.png -depth 32 -define quantum:format=floating-point rgb:out.rgb
```

For example, if you create a 1x1 white image like this

```
convert -size 1x1 xc:white -depth 32 -define quantum:format=floating-point rgb:out.rgb
```

you get a 12-byte image like this

```
xxd out.rgb
0000000: 0000 803f 0000 803f 0000 803f
```

If you create a 1x1 black image like this

```
convert -size 1x1 xc:black -depth 32 -define quantum:format=floating-point rgb:out.rgb
```

you get a 12-byte image like this

```
xxd out.rgb
0000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: Sorry! that float32 that i wrote is wrong, i want a 32 uint output! 8 uint maybe is good too but i don't want lose too much informations