# Numpy 8-bits images conversion to 16/32-bits images before cvtColor() in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, colors

I was doing some testing based on my understanding from reading the documentation but stumble upon this.

Source: [NumPy convert 8-bit to 16/32-bit image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444334/numpy-convert-8-bit-to-16-32-bit-image)

```
 i = cv2.imread(imgNameIn, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR) # Need to be sure to have a 8-bit input
 img = np.array(i, dtype=np.uint16) # This line only change the type, not values
 img *= 256 # Now we get the good values in 16 bit format
```

But from what I read here
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html

To scale down from 32bits to 8 bits one have to divide by 255 instead of 256 mentioned above which I got from the other post? This code below is what I am trying to play around with.

Would appreciate if anyone able to check if I have done the scaling correctly.
**I am asking this question mainly to confirm whether the supposed casting value is 255 or 256?**

Comment: Always 255. The largest value a float image should occupy (for display and use in functions that would saturate it) is 1. So to scale back to `uint8`, you multiply the largest `float` value (1) by 255 to get the largest `uint8` value (255). And similar, the largest `uint8` number is 255 so to get to the highest `float` value, you should divide by 255 to get back to 1. Simple as. On another note, please use better variable names. And be weary with assigning images to other images; this may reference the exact same thing in memory. Use `.copy()` on numpy arrays to create new copies.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I have now updated the post. May I know what do you mean by new copies?                                                                     The idea of my code is to test whether conversion of 8bits image to float32 before cvtColor() to prevent information lost. My main purpose is to preserve the information as accurate as possible since i could not save float32 images using cv2.imwrite, i have to somehow scale it down to 8bits again(without any information lost) to save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to disagree with the answer to the question you link. Format `uint8` can represent 256 values of integers i.e., integers from 0 to 255 `(2^8 - 1)`. 256 cannot be represented as `uint8`. `uint16` will range from 0 to `(2^16 - 1) = 65535`.

Therefore, if you want a 16-bit, images with 65535 color levels and if the intensity values of the images are in the range `[0, 1]` when you read the image and in format `float`, you need to multiply the values by 65535 and to and then to convert the array to `uint16`.

It is good practice to cast the type of your end result as the very last step of the operations you perform. This is mainly for two reasons: 
 - If you perform divisions or multiplications by float, the result will return a float and you will need to change the type again. 
 - In general (in the mathematical sense of the term), a transformation
   from float to integer introduces errors. Casting the type at the
   very end of the operations prevents error propagation.

To go back to 8-bit i.e., 256 color levels, you need to multiply all values by `255 / 65535`.

The same reasoning holds for 32-bit images with `2^32 = 4,294,967,296` possible intensity values, i.e, values in the range `[0, 4294967295]`. These number becoming big, you will rather work with 32-bit images in the float format where values are contained in the range `[0, 1]`.

PS: I found your code quite confusing and did not go through in detail. Understanding that the 8/16/32/64-bit format is a representation of the number of possible intensity levels in the image is the key that should allow you to understand the transformations you are doing on the images.

Comment: "The result of a multiplication or the division operation is always float." No it's not; `(np.uint16(5)*255).dtype => dtype('int64')` and `(np.uint16(5)*np.uint16(255)).dtype => dtype('uint16')` for example. Only division always returns a `float` in Python.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Oops, I have been writing too fast. You're of course right on this point! I corrected and added more context. It's just a mistake I have seen too many times working with images: Casting an integer type, performing some operations, and then wondering why the next library function you call doesn't work though your transformed the pixel's values to integer (that became float meanwhile).

Comment: Absolutely, just wanted to give you the chance to edit this good answer!

Comment: @Eskapp Thank you for your well explained and detailed answer , I have now updated the code(go through in detail) and also posted the result. I noticed something might be going wrong with the conversion? as the float32 result shown is different from uint16 and uint8.

Comment: @Eskapp i still could not figure out this bit "It is good practice to cast the type of your end result as the very last step of the operations you perform. This is mainly for two reasons: - If you perform divisions or multiplications by float, the result will return a float and you will need to change the type again"   I did that and it give me "TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'B') according to the casting rule ''same_kind'' "

Comment: @SacreD which version of Python do you use? I assumed Python3 but if you are using Python2 the division operator works differently. I'm going to go through your code as soon as I have time :)

Comment: @Eskapp i am using python 3

Comment: @SacredD You got the error by writing `im /= 255` right? This doesn't work because on the left hand side `im` is a numpy array. When I do `im = im / 255` it works even if `im` is `uint8`. I'll check the way outputs look later.

Comment: @Eskapp Sorry if i got you confused, for the first conversion i actually got it work with either im /= 255 OR im *= 1./255 OR im = im / 255,  just that I am saying I need to convert the datatype to float32 only I am allowed to proceed with the operation without getting any error messages as mentioned.

Comment: @Eskapp but for the conversion from uint16 to uint8 after cvtColor, I can only get it work using im = im*(255./65535) instead of im *= (255./65535). I will get error mesage "TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint16') with casting rule 'same_kind' " . I suspect it has something to do with upcasting behaviour

Comment: @Eskapp Thank you for your detailed explanation for the output verification I have since move it to new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052359/different-images-visual-for-32-16-8bits-data-type-images-after-cvtcolor-conver

Comment: ok great, I was thinking of asking you to move it to a new question to keep the rule, 1 post, 1 question. Got too busy to look at it. Best of luck in solving your issue :)

Comment: @Eskapp Still did not get any response yet :(..hopefully you have the time to look at it in the next few days.