# Numpy 8 and 32 bits image data type after cvtColor() conversion to LAB colorspace

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, colors

I am trying to understand how LAB work in OpenCV. Previously open up a post on [HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052359/numpy-8-16-32-bits-image-data-type-after-cvtcolor-conversion-to-hsv-colorspace)  I was playing and testing with the datatype after the conversion to LAB

LAB standard range of for the pixel data in Lightness = 0-100, a* = -127 to +127, b* = -127 to +127. But I am confused with the data shown in openCV. Could anyone help me check if I am doing the conversion of datatype and scaling correct?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread(r'G:\Checkerboardfordummies.png')
cv2.namedWindow('im', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('im', im)
print(im)
print(im.dtype)

#Conversion from 8uint to float32 before cvtColor()
im = im.astype(np.float32)          #Cast Image data type        
im /= 255.                          #Scale value to float32 range 0-1
print(im)
print(im.dtype)
#Colour Space Conversion to LAB
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
cv2.namedWindow('Float32_Checkerboard', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Float32_Checkerboard', im)
cv2.imwrite('Float32_Checkerboard.png',im)

#Conversion from float32 to uint8
im = im*(255.)                #Scale value to uint8 range 0-255
im = im.astype(np.uint8)            #Cast Image data type
print(im)
print(im.dtype)
cv2.namedWindow('uint8_Checkerboard', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('uint8_Checkerboard', im)
cv2.imwrite('uint8_Checkerboard.png',im)
```

Testing image:

[image]

Testing result with conversion

[image]

I am not sure which one is the expected colour to observe in LAB? 8uint or the one  with float32? I thought it should display same colour? something might be wrong with my scaling

This is the printed out data for reference: It seem like scaling back to 8uint is wrong looking at the value

```
>>> 

[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 ..., 
 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
uint8
[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 ..., 
 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
float32
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]]

 ..., 
 [[156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  [156   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
uint8
>>>
```

**EDIT**: After discussion with Danmasek...managed to display the images correctly in both 8bits and 32bits

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread(r'G:\Checkerboardfordummies.png')
cv2.namedWindow('im', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('im', im)
print(im)
print(im.dtype)

#Conversion from 8uint to float32 before cvtColor()
im = im.astype(np.float32)          #Cast Image data type        
im /= 255                        #Scale value to float32 range 0-1
print(im)
print(im.dtype)
#Colour Space Conversion to HSV
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
cv2.namedWindow('Float32_Checkerboard', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Float32_Checkerboard', im)
cv2.imwrite('Float32_Checkerboard.png',im)


#Conversion from float32 to uint8
im[:,:,0] = im[:,:,0]*(255./100)#Scale value to uint8 range 0-255
im[:,:,1] = (im[:,:,1] + 128)/255
im[:,:,2] = (im[:,:,2] + 128)/255

im = im.astype(np.uint8)            #Cast Image data type
print(im)
print(im.dtype)
cv2.namedWindow('uint8_Checkerboard', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('uint8_Checkerboard', im)
cv2.imwrite('uint8_Checkerboard.png',im)

cv2.imwrite('uint8_Checkerboard.png',im)
```

Got this result :

[image]

Printed data: the conversion from 32 to 8 bits....its still printing 255 on the L channel after the scaling. Very weird

```
>>> 
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 ..., 
 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
uint8
[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 ..., 
 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
float32
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]

 ..., 
 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
uint8
>>>
```

Comment: Considering there are only 2 distinct colours on that checker board, why not just try it with a simple 1x2 image and ditch the remaining ~150000 pixels? Also, not storing everything in a single variable would make comparisons easier as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 2 distinct colours, so let's simplify it and only use an image with 2 pixels, and eliminate the tens of thousands of redundant pixels that only make the behaviour more difficult to observe.

As such, we can simplify the whole thing to this onliner:

```
cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]], dtype=np.float32), cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

which returns

```
 array([[[   0.,    0.,    0.],
    [ 100.,    0.,    0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Well, look at the second pixel.

At this point, let's consult [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) for this kind of colour conversion.

> This outputs 0≤L≤100, −127≤a≤127, −127≤b≤127 . The values are then converted to the destination data type:
>
> - 8-bit images: L←L∗255/100,a←a+128,b←b+128
> - 16-bit images: (currently not supported)
> - 32-bit images: L, a, and b are left as is

We've got a 32 bit image, so the values are "left as is" (i.e in the ranges `0≤L≤100, −127≤a≤127, −127≤b≤127`)

Hence, multiplying the result by 255 and casting it to an 8 bit unsigned integer will leave you with nonsense due to overflow.

---

> But how should i scale and convert back from float32 to 8bits in the LAB colorspace without experiencing overflow.

Apply some elementary math (hinted at by the quoted documentation): `L←L∗255/100,a←a+128,b←b+128`

```
float_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]], dtype=np.float32), cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
# Channel L
float_img[:,:,0] = float_img[:,:,0] * (255.0/100.0)
# Channels a and b
float_img[:,:,1:] = float_img[:,:,1:] + 128

result = np.uint8(float_img)
```

The `result` being

```
array([[[  0, 128, 128],
        [255, 128, 128]]], dtype=uint8)
```

For comparison:

```
>>> cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[0,0,0],[255,255,255]]], dtype=np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
array([[[  0, 128, 128],
        [255, 128, 128]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: But how should i scale and convert back from float32 to 8bits in the LAB colorspace without experiencing overflow

Comment: Maybe read the docs I quoted? It says it right there: `8-bit images: L←L∗255/100,a←a+128,b←b+128`

Comment: edited my question to try what you mentioned. I got a weird image display.

Comment: i am debugging what went wrong...will update in a minute i think i know why

Comment: The `split` and `merge` are at best unnecessary, since you're already accessing the individual channels using numpy indexing.

Comment: update the ques with result, still got some overflowing issue after switching it.... couldnt identify which value is causing that.  What condition should i put to catch the overflow?

Comment: the mathematical scaling seem logically correct to me but the data shown otherwise...still got different image display for float32 and uint8

Comment: You still pass the result of `cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)` with a float image directly to `cv2.imshow`. That function expects values in range 0.0-1.0, however the result of conversion has range 0-100 for first channel, and -127 - 127 for the other two. `imshow` clamps the values.

Comment: If you want to visually compare, you need to do a similar transformation for the floating point, as you have done for the uint8 -- just scale into range 0.0-1.0, rather than 0-255. i.e. `L←L/100,a←(a+128)/255,b←(b+128)/255`

Comment: have you tried it with my images above i got black image now after L←L/100,a←(a+128)/255,b←(b+128)/255....But i was thinking by scaling it back into range of 0.0-1.0, would that be back to the original form of 32 bits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154623/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-sacred).